# How to disable a UIbutton in a UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

Hello I currently have a UItableview and in that tableview i made a custom cell that contains two UIButtons. This is to achieve a up and downvote function. I'm just wondering how would i disable these uibuttons in the cell after the users click on it and not affect other cells buttons that is using the same template?

I've tried running a function in the controller of the uitableviewcell. when the button is clicked i would disable the buttons but using this method made me run into a bug where other cells button's will be disabled too.

```
@IBOutlet weak var down: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var up: UIButton!


@IBAction func upVoteButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{

    self.up.isEnabled = false

}
@IBAction func downVoteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.up.isEnabled = false
}
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: table cells are reusable as soon as you scroll the new cells are reusable cells.so if you disabled the one visible before the new one will also be disabled.You can try using (prepareforreuse ) method in cell custom class and achieve your target.You can look into how that function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i can think i would prefer to create an array of checkList:[Bool] and in view did load method or in any method where you are trying to setup the table then configure the array of length of your table as true and when @IBAction is called then do this

```
let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let tableview = cell.superview?.superview as! UITableView;
    let index = tableview.indexPath(for: cell);
    let n = index?.section/row // whatever u r using
     checkList[n] = false;
```

now in override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
do this

```
cell.button.isEnabled = checkList[indexPath.section/row]
```

Comment: it is just an overview and not the exact code so if you face any problem please ask

Comment: Thanks I will try this out!

Comment: hi Adam I tried working around this method. I am not able to access the variable checkList in my IBAction method. The checkList array is stored in a viewcontroller class while the IBaction is in a UItableviewcell class. Any suggestions? This means when i try to run checkList[n] = false. i get the error " use of unresolve identifier"

Comment: access it as `youviewController.checkList[n]` and don"t forget to add this line after that `yourviewController.tableView.reloadData()` do tell me your result

Comment: Yes I figured i had to reloadData(). This works! Thanks a bunch